# Path Analysis with multiple mediators and predictors

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I recently started studying SEMs and path analysis in particular to analyze a data set. I have the following model, and I want to make sure I specified it correctly with `Lavaan`.

The goal of this model is to explain the variance of `Y` using the set of parameters `X1` to `X6`. We suspect that some variables, such as `X3`, have a direct and indirect effect on `Y`. Thus, we modeled it with SEMs. I based my understanding of `lavaan` on this [blog post](https://paolotoffanin.wordpress.com/2017/06/04/multiple-mediation-example/).

Could you please tell me if this is correctly specified?

[image]

```
model <- '
          # Model
          Y  ~ b1 * X1 + b2 * X2 + c1 * X3 + c2 * X4 + c3 * X5
          X1 ~ a1 * X3 + a3 * X6
          X2 ~ a2 * X3

          # Indirect Effect
          indirect1 := a1 * b1
          indirect1 := a3 * b1
          indirect3 := a2 * b2

          # Contrast
          con1 := a1 * b1 - a2 * b2
          con2 := (a3 - a1) * b1 

          # Total effect
          total1 := c1 + (a1 * b1) + (a2 * b2)

          # Covariance of mediators
          X1 ~~ X2
         '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's right.

Your model is drawn a little strangely. I would call x1 and x2 y variables, as they are endogenous.

I would put all your (true) x variables together - that's x3 - x6 in a line. Some of these predict x1 and x2, others predict y. You might want to draw correlations between the x's (the true x's) as these will be in the model.

If you label your paths using the labels in the syntax, it's much easier for someone to relate the two to each other.

You probably want to correlate x1 and x2 (after renaming them).

It's not common to put the errors inside ellipses. They are normally draw with a label and arrow only.